# Rename volume in docker compose, with docker derived from postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, rename, volume

I have this docker-compose

```html
version: '3.7'

services:

  app-db:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-pg
    image: app-pg:1.0.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: app
    volumes:
       - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh
       - v-app-pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql
       - v-app-pglog:/data/var/log/postgresql
       - v-app-pgconf:/etc/postgresql


    
  app-main:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-tar-cp
    image: app-main:1.0.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
volumes:
  v-app-pgdata:
    name: v-app-pgdata
  v-app-pglog:
    name: v-app-pglog
  v-app-pgconf:
    name: v-app-pgconf
```

so an app container and a postgres derived container:

```html
#docker build -t app-pg:1.0.0 -f Dockerfile-pg .
#docker run -d --name appC-pg -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=postgres app-pg:1.0.0

FROM postgres:12.1

MAINTAINER xxx

#ARG A_DB_USER='postgres'
#ARG A_DB_PASS='postgres'
ARG A_DB_NAME='app'
ARG A_TZ='Europe/Zurich'

#ENV DB_USER=${A_DB_USER}
#ENV DB_PASS=${A_DB_PASS}
ENV DB_NAME=${A_DB_NAME}
ENV TZ=${A_TZ}

# Adjusting Timezone in the system
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean

# install postgis
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgis && \
    apt-get clean

USER postgres

#Add password "postgres" to user postgres, create db, add .sql
#RUN /etc/init.d/postgresql start && \
#    psql --command "ALTER USER ${DB_USER} WITH PASSWORD '${DB_PASS}'; SET TIME ZONE '${TZ}';" && \
#    createdb -O ${DB_USER} ${DB_NAME} -E UTF8 && \
#    psql -d ${DB_NAME} -c 'CREATE EXTENSION postgis'

EXPOSE 5432
```

My problem is that postgres default dockerfile have this line:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

So even if I create a named Volumes with the same folder, my docker-compose create 4 and not 3 volumes, one unnamed due to that line.
How is it possible solve this issue?

Comment: i'm thinking its the initdb doing it. try removing it
"- ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-user-db.sh".

Comment: maybe like this ?                 `environment:
                        - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql`

Comment: @RajVerma I don't know why but the entrypoint doesn't create a volume, the volume containes /var/lib/postgresql/data so I think that is the volume that come from the postgres official dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and I solved it by editing the `docker-compose.yml` the following way:

1. Create a volume for the data

```
volumes:
    v-app-pgdata:
```

2. In your declaration of the database service, in the volumes clause, you need to change `- v-app-pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql` to:

```
- v-app-pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The problem was that you where not mounting the volume to the correct place, and therefore, it had to create another volume that is declared in the base image `VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data`. If you run this container without attaching a volume to this mount point, it will automatically create it, and with a random name.

However, it has been pointed out to me that if the OP strictly needs a volume in `/var/lib/postgresql` then this solution wont work.

Hope this helps, as it worked for me.